# htaccess change for redirecting Pages with Page Number

Tags: .htaccess, paging

I have recently migrated the site into a better design . Earlier we used to have lot of page numbers but in the new site we have implemented Ajax Based Lazy Loading. As a result , I want to redirect the Pages with Page Numbers into the Main Page. I am in need of the following

To redirect a URL like below

```
 job.php?filter=&&strow=40
```

TO

```
 job.php
```

And another one

From URL

```
 searchresult.php?sid=1&&mainid=50&&lanid=&&maincat=singer&&link=ctry&&order=&&couid=&&strow=3
```

to

```
 our_singer.php
```

(pls note the word singer in the long url, if it is dancer the url will be our_dancer.php)

Please could you help me

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule ^job\.php$ /job.php? [R,L]
RewriteRule ^searchresult\.php$ /our_singer.php? [R,L]
```

"?" at the end of the target removes the Query string from url.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried but it did not redirect to job.php in the URL.

Comment: Any other rules in your htaccess file?

Comment: There are other rules but does not look those will effect this